# update and insert data nested array up-to 4 level

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
var continent = new mongoose.Schema({
    continent: {
        type:string,
    },
    country: [{
        country: {
            type: String,
        },
        currency: {
            type: String,
        },
        state: [{
            state_name: {
                type: string,
            },
           company:[{
               location:{
                   type:string,
               },
               loc_type:{
                   type:string,
               },
               employee:[{
                   emp_name:{
                       type:string
                   },
                   emp_age:{
                       type:Number,
                   }
               }]
           }]
        }]
    }]
})
```

I have to push value inside the company and employee also update the individual value 
I tried this code

```
var data_push = {
    loc_type:"urban",
    location:"india",
}
var continent = await Line_data.update(
    {continent_name:continent_name, 'continent.country_name':country_name,'continent.country_name.state_name':state_name }, 
    { "$push": { "country.$.state_name.company":  data_push} }
)
```

I face problem in 3 and 4 layer.
can anybody help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of MongoDB [`$[element]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) operator and [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) option to achieve what you need;

```
var data_push = {
    loc_type:"urban",
    location:"india",
}

Line_data.update(
  {
    continent: continent_name,
  },
  {
    $push: {
      'country.$[countryElement].state.$[stateElement].company': data_push,
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      {
        'countryElement.country': country_name,
      },
      {
        'stateElement.state': state_name,
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

What if you want to go deeper e.g add an employee? It's pretty much the same approach as above, you just need to extend the elementMatches and arrayFilters:

```
Line_data.update(
  {
    continent: continent_name,
  },
  {
    $push: {
      'country.$[countryElement].state.$[stateElement].company.$[companyElement].employee.$[employeeElement]': employee_data,
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { 'countryElement.country': country_name },
      { 'stateElement.state': state_name },
      { 'companyElement.location': company_location },
      { 'employeeElement.emp_name': employee_name }
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what if, I want to add data in employee collection.

Comment: I believe by employee collection, you mean the employee array nested in the company field. It's pretty much the same approach, you just need to extend the element matches and array filters. I would update the answer to include a scenario of if you want to add an employee document.